# What type should I use for a regular "payload-less" action when using Redux Toolkit with Typescript?

Tags: typescript, redux, redux-toolkit

Here is what I'm doing for my slice reducers when my actions require a `payload`:

```
import { createSlice, Action, PayloadAction } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

type SOME_ACTION = PayloadAction<{ value: string }>

const SOME_SLICE = createSlice({
  name: "SOME_SLICE",
  initialState: getInitialState(),
  reducers: {
    SOME_ACTION(state, action: SOME_ACTION) {
      const { value }  = action.payload;
      state.someProp = value;
    }
  }
});
```

But some of my action currently don't require a `payload`. Although they don't require it right now, they might do in the future. So I would like to add some type to the action, even if I'm not currently using the action inside the reducer.

```
import { createSlice, Action, PayloadAction } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

type SOME_ACTION = ???         // WHAT SHOULD I TYPE A "Payload-less" ACTION?

const SOME_SLICE = createSlice({
  name: "SOME_SLICE",
  initialState: getInitialState(),
  reducers: {
    SOME_ACTION(state, action: SOME_ACTION) {
      // CURRENTLY action IS NOT BEING USED HERE. BUT MIGHT BE IN THE FUTURE
      state.loading = true;
    }
  }
});
```

Is `PayloadAction<void>` the answer for this?

Comment: If you don't want to use it now it can be a good idea to set it to `PayloadAction<null>` so TypeScript will warn you if you try to consume `action.payload`. If you don't matter, you can use `PayloadAction<any>`.

Comment: Thanks. But if I set `PayloadAction<null>`, won't Typescript complain when I call the action, like `dispatch(SOME_ACTION())`  saying that I have to pass `null` as the argument? Same for `any`, it will expect an argument, won't it? EDIT: Just tested it, and it does behave like that. Can't use `null` nor `any`.

Comment: `PayloadAction<void>` seems like a very valid approach. You could do `PayloadAction<void | unknown>` to express that there can be an object passed into it and you don't currently care which one. But I think the first one matches your intent better.

Comment: @pascalpuetz Yeah, so far it seems to be working. Just want to confirm if this is really the way to go. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not familiar with redux could add this case (that use the `dispatch` function) in the question?

Comment: `void` is the default type for the `PayloadAction` so you can just use `PayloadAction`.

Comment: @johannchopin you are right. That also works. I think I'll go with `PayloadAction<void>`, though. I think it makes it more clear.